# how to expose restful web service using JSON with Spring MVC

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

I am new in Restful web services with JSON, I want to expose and consume the Restful web services using Spring MVC. Can you please guide me how can I do that. Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: You can to search rest, json, spirng mvc . try.. and you take error and your code. come back.

Answer (score 0):

Spring documentation is a good starting point. Take a look at this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/